# JPA Criteria Query selectCase on join expression

Tags: jpa, criteria-api

I have a Tuple query that is loading some values and a relationship (join) count. I'm trying to get a third column that is based on a select case value from that join whether or not the join collection contains some value, but I'm really struggling.

The general gist is that Assets can be favorited by users through a UserFavorite object. I am trying to select 3 things:

1) Asset id
2) count of times it has been favorited
3**) whether this asset has been favorited by the user requesting the query

In SQL land, I do this:

```
select distinct a.asset_id, count(u.asset_id) as favorite_count, case when u.user_id in (XXXX) then 1 else 0 end as is_favorite_for_user from asset a left join user_favorite u on (a.asset_id = u.asset_id) group by a.asset_id;
```

The first 2 parts of the Tuple query below are working fine, but I can't get the rest:

```
Root<Asset> assetRoot = assetQuery.from(Asset.class);
SetJoin<Asset, UserFavorite> userFavoriteJoin = assetRoot.join(Asset_.userFavorites, JoinType.LEFT);
assetQuery.select(criteriaBuilder.tuple(
    assetRoot.get(Asset_.assetId),
    criteriaBuilder.count(userFavoriteJoin)
));
assetQuery.distinct(true);
assetQuery.groupBy(assetRoot.get(Asset_.assetId));
```

I can't figure out how to do the select case/in statement in JPA Criteria. Any thoughts?

Is there a better way to do this than the select/case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried following?

```
    assetQuery.select(criteriaBuilder.tuple(
            assetRoot.get(Asset_.assetId),
            criteriaBuilder.count(userFavoriteJoin),
            criteriaBuilder.selectCase().when(userFavoriteJoin.get(UserFavorite_.userId).in("XXXX"), 1).otherwise(0)
    ));
```

Comment: This worked out really well. I wasn't too far off, but I was running into https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-4700 when I tried to cast my selectCase (<Boolean>selectCase...) and use Boolean.TRUE and Boolean.FALSE instead of 1 and 0 in my return type. Thanks again!